# bootstrap работает только на одной странице Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, bootstrap, header

Подключил bootstrap через header.php.

На главной странице работает все прекрасно.

Создал еще одну страницу, там ни bootstrap ни подключенные шрифты не работают.

**Вопрос заключается в следующем:** из-за чего такое может происходить и как решить?

Comment: А если посмотреть исходник страницы в браузере, там видны подключенные css?

Comment: А вы подключили под другую страницу CSS?

Comment: @DmitryKozlov да, подключены css плагинов и css установленной темы

Comment: @insider а разве для построения страницы не используются те же самые header.php и footer.php? Ведь как минимум футер на новой странице тот же, что и на главной. Или я неправильно понимаю?

Comment: Покажите ссылку? Похоже, что у вас несколько header.php в теме. И стили надо подключать не через шапку, а через `wp_enqueue_style`

Comment: @mihdan файл с именем header.php точно один, но вот действительно, на самих страницах в коде в теге <header> различный код. neliasart.com.ua - здесь все нормально, здесь (neliasart.com.ua/info) - нет. P.S: не судите за кривоту - это мой первый сайт. Но если хедеры отрабатывают разные, то почему футер один и тот же?  Попробую подключить bootstrap через `wp_enque_style`

Comment: Как успехи в подключении бутстрапа?

Comment: @mihdan Действительно, проблема была в неправильном подключении, через `wp-enque_script` и `wp_enque_style` все работает. Спасибо за наводку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Wordpress все стили и скрипты стоит подключать через functions.php.
Для правильного подключения бутстрапа достаточно через ftp залить bootstrap.css и bootstrap.js в соответсвующие папки, а в functions.php добавить следующие строчки:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.css', array( ), false, 'all' );
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.js', array( ), false, 'all' );
```